# Adding a drop down select menu to Data Table using array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable, datatables

I am using datatable for the first time and got into a little bit of an issue. My first attempt I wrote the PHP code like this:

```
<?php

$city = ($_GET['city']);
$sort = ($_GET['sort']);
$sortorder = ($_GET['sortorder']);

if ($city == "la"){
      $citylong = "Los Angeles";
}
if ($city == "oc"){
      $citylong = "Orange County";
}
if ($city == "sf"){
      $citylong = "San Francisco";
}

?>
<h5>Reservations for <?php echo $citylong; ?></h5>
<table id="datatable1" class="table table-striped" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Booking Date</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Class</th>
      <th>Pick Up</th>
      <th>Duration</th>
      <th>Drop Off</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Coverage</th>
      <th>Quote</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php
include 'dbconfig.php';

$sql="SELECT bookingid, bookingdatetime, firstname, lastname, address, city, state, country, post, dlnum, dlexp, dlcountry, phone, email, addcomments, pickuploc, droploc, pickupdatetime, dropdatetime, class, numofdrivers, coverage, driversage, roadsideass, afterhoursdrop, promo, quotedprice, status, remoteip FROM reservations WHERE pickuploc='" . $city . "' ORDER BY " . $sort . " " . $sortorder;
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

      $bookingdate = new DateTime($row['bookingdatetime']);
      $bookingdatetimefancy = $bookingdate->format('m/d/y \@\ h:i a');

      $pickupdatetime = new DateTime($row['pickupdatetime']);
      $pickupdatetimefancy = $pickupdatetime->format('m/d/y \@\ h:i a');


      $dropdatetime = new DateTime($row['dropdatetime']);
      $dropdatetimefancy = $dropdatetime->format('m/d/y \@\ h:i a');

      $pickupdate = new DateTime($pickupdatetime->format('Y-m-d'));
      $dropdate = new DateTime($dropdatetime->format('Y-m-d'));


      $inbetween = $pickupdate->diff($dropdate)->days;
      $duration = str_pad($inbetween, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);


      $statusConfirmed = "";
      $statusUnconfirmed = "";
      $statusOpen = "";
      $statusClosed = "";
      $statusCanceled = "";

      if($row['status']=="Confirmed"){
      $statusConfirmed = 'selected';
      }

      if($row['status']=="Unconfirmed"){
      $statusUnconfirmed = 'selected';
      }

      if($row['status']=="Open"){
      $statusOpen = 'selected';
      }

      if($row['status']=="Closed"){
      $statusClosed = 'selected';
      }

      if($row['status']=="Canceled"){
      $statusCanceled = 'selected';
      }

      if ($row['pickuploc'] == $row['droploc']) {
            $otherdropoff = "";
      }else{
            $otherdropoff = " (" . $row['droploc'] . ") ";
      }


echo  '<tr>
      <td>' . $row['bookingid'] .'</td>
      <td>' . $bookingdatetimefancy .'</td>
      <td>' . $row['firstname'] . " " . $row['lastname'] .'</td>

      <td>' . $row['class'] .'</td>

      <td>' . $pickupdatetimefancy .'</td>
      <td>' . $duration . " days" .'</td>
      <td>' . $dropdatetimefancy . $otherdropoff .'</td>

      <td>' . $row['driversage'] .'</td>
      <td>' . $row['coverage'] .'</td>

      <td>$' . $row['quotedprice'] .'</td>
      <td><select name="resstatus" id="resstatus' . $row['bookingid'] .'" onchange="changeresstatus(' . $row['bookingid'] . ');">
            <option ' . $statusConfirmed. ' value="Confirmed">Confirmed</option>
            <option ' . $statusUnconfirmed . ' value="Unconfirmed">Unconfirmed</option>
            <option ' . $statusOpen . ' value="Open">Open</option>
            <option ' . $statusClosed . ' value="Closed">Closed</option>
            <option ' . $statusCanceled . ' value="Canceled">Canceled</option>
</select></td>


    </tr>';

} 
?>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Which was pretty sloppy, and since I want to add an auto updating feature in the future I thought it would be best to transfer everything using a JSON array, so now it's being done like this:

```
<?php

$city = ($_GET['city']);

include 'dbconfig.php';

$sql="SELECT bookingid, bookingdatetime, firstname, lastname, address, city, state, country, post, dlnum, dlexp, dlcountry, phone, email, addcomments, pickuploc, droploc, pickupdatetime, dropdatetime, class, numofdrivers, coverage, driversage, roadsideass, afterhoursdrop, promo, quotedprice, status, remoteip FROM reservations WHERE pickuploc='" . $city . "'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

$arr = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

      $bookingdate = new DateTime($row['bookingdatetime']);
      $bookingdatetimefancy = $bookingdate->format('m/d/y \@\ h:i a');

      $pickupdatetime = new DateTime($row['pickupdatetime']);
      $pickupdatetimefancy = $pickupdatetime->format('m/d/y \@\ h:i a');


      $dropdatetime = new DateTime($row['dropdatetime']);
      $dropdatetimefancy = $dropdatetime->format('m/d/y \@\ h:i a');

      $pickupdate = new DateTime($pickupdatetime->format('Y-m-d'));
      $dropdate = new DateTime($dropdatetime->format('Y-m-d'));


      $inbetween = $pickupdate->diff($dropdate)->days;
      $duration = str_pad($inbetween, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);


      $statusConfirmed = "";
      $statusUnconfirmed = "";
      $statusOpen = "";
      $statusClosed = "";
      $statusCanceled = "";

      if($row['status']=="Confirmed"){
      $statusConfirmed = 'selected';
      }

      if($row['status']=="Unconfirmed"){
      $statusUnconfirmed = 'selected';
      }

      if($row['status']=="Open"){
      $statusOpen = 'selected';
      }

      if($row['status']=="Closed"){
      $statusClosed = 'selected';
      }

      if($row['status']=="Canceled"){
      $statusCanceled = 'selected';
      }

      if ($row['pickuploc'] == $row['droploc']) {
            $otherdropoff = "";
      }else{
            $otherdropoff = " (" . $row['droploc'] . ") ";
      }


    array_push($arr, array(
        'id'                  => $row['bookingid'],
        'bookingdatetime'     => $bookingdatetimefancy,
        'name'                => $row['firstname'] . " " . $row['lastname'],
        'class'               => $row['class'],
        'pickupdatetime'      => $pickupdatetimefancy,
        'duration'            => $duration . " days",
        'dropdatetime'        => $dropdatetimefancy . " " . $otherdropoff,
        'age'                 => $row['driversage'],
        'coverage'            => $row['coverage'],
        'quote'               => "$" . $row['quotedprice'],
        'status'              => $row['status']
    ));

} 

// Send the $date_ranges as JSON.
$json = json_encode($arr); // '[{"start": "2019-08-18", "end": "2019-08-19"}]'
echo $json;
```

and here is my Java Script:

```
function getres() {
        $.ajax({
            type : 'get',
            url  : 'reservations2.php?city='+document.getElementById("cityselect").value,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success :  function(result)
            {
                if (document.getElementById("cityselect").value == "la"){
                    city = "Los Angeles";
                }
                if (document.getElementById("cityselect").value == "oc"){
                    city = "Orange County";
                }
                if (document.getElementById("cityselect").value == "sf"){
                    city = "San Francisco";
                }
                restitle.innerText = "Reservations for "+city;
                $('#resdatatable').dataTable({
                    data: result,
                    destroy: true,
                    columns: [
                    { data: 'id', title: 'ID' },
                    { data: 'bookingdatetime', title: 'Booking Date' },
                    { data: 'name', title: 'Name' },
                    { data: 'class', title: 'Class' },
                    { data: 'pickupdatetime', title: 'Pick up' },
                    { data: 'duration', title: 'Duration' },
                    { data: 'dropdatetime', title: 'Drop off' },
                    { data: 'age', title: 'Age' },
                    { data: 'coverage', title: 'Coverage' },
                    { data: 'quote', title: 'Quote' },
                    { data: 'status', title: 'Status' },

                    ]
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

As you can see I lost the functionality of the select drop down menu when changing to passing the data with the array. How can I add that drop down select back in?

I need to put the selects back in, I need them to have a unique ID that matches the row ID, and I need them to have an onchange function.

Comment: With the `change` event's `event` param, you can get `event.target` to determine the `id` from the row.

Comment: Can you provide some sample rendered HTML (without the PHP) as well?

Comment: I don't know how to get the rendered html, I can give you the JSON response?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl - to be 100% clear - we are no longer using the first code example. We are using the second code examples using JSON.

Comment: OK, I believe I figured out your issue, you can strap a renderer to the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a `renderer` for the "Status" column.

I also created a jQuery plugin to alternatively scan a table and change the last call in every row to a dropdown.

I also commented out headers and fields to reduce the number of columns.

---

#### Status dropdown data

```js
let statusList = [{
  id: 'Confirmed',
  text: 'Confirmed'
}, {
  id: 'Unconfirmed',
  text: 'Unconfirmed'
}, {
  id: 'Open',
  text: 'Open'
}, {
  id: 'Closed',
  text: 'Closed'
}, {
  id: 'Canceled',
  text: 'Canceled'
}];
```

#### Status column

```js
{
  data: 'status',
  title: 'Status',
  render: function(data, type, row) {
    let isKnown = statusList.filter(function(k) {
      return k.id === data;
    }).length > 0;
    if (isKnown) {
      return $('<select>', {
        id: 'resstatus-' + row.id, // custom id
        value: data
      }).append(statusList.map(function(knownStatus) {
        let $option = $('<option>', {
          text: knownStatus.text,
          value: knownStatus.id
        });
        if (row.status === knownStatus.id) {
          $option.attr('selected', 'selected')
        }
        return $option;
      })).on('change', function() {
        changeresstatus(row.id); // Call change with row ID
      }).prop('outerHTML');
    } else {
      return data;
    }
  }
}
```

---

### Working Demo

```js
let result = getResult();
let statusList = getStatusList();

$('#resdatatable').dataTable({
  data: result,
  destroy: true,
  columns: [
    { data: 'id', title: 'ID' },
    { data: 'bookingdatetime', title: 'Booking Date' },
    { data: 'name', title: 'Name' },
    //{ data: 'class', title: 'Class' },
    //{ data: 'pickupdatetime', title: 'Pick up' },
    //{ data: 'duration', title: 'Duration' },
    //{ data: 'dropdatetime', title: 'Drop off' },
    { data: 'age', title: 'Age' },
    //{ data: 'coverage', title: 'Coverage' },
    //{ data: 'quote', title: 'Quote' },
    {
      data: 'status',
      title: 'Status',
      render: function(data, type, row) {
        let isKnown = statusList.filter(function(k) { return k.id === data; }).length > 0;
        if (isKnown) {
          return $('<select>', {
            id: 'resstatus-' + row.id, // custom id
            value: data
          }).append(statusList.map(function(knownStatus) {
            let $option = $('<option>', {
              text: knownStatus.text,
              value: knownStatus.id
            });
            if (row.status === knownStatus.id) {
              $option.attr('selected', 'selected')
            }
            return $option;
          })).on('change', function() {
            changeresstatus(row.id); // Call change with row ID
          }).prop('outerHTML');
        } else {
          return data;
        }
      }
    }
  ]
});

/**
 * jQuery plugin to convert text in a cell to a dropdown
 */
(function($) {
  $.fn.createDropDown = function(items) {
    let oldTxt = this.text();
    let isKnown = items.filter(function(k) { return k.id === oldTxt; }).length > 0;
    if (isKnown) {
      this.empty().append($('<select>').append(items.map(function(item) {
        let $option = $('<option>', {
          text: item.text,
          value: item.id
        });
        if (item.id === oldTxt) {
          $option.attr('selected', 'selected')
        }
        return $option;
      })));
    }
    return this;
  };
})(jQuery);

// If you remove the renderer above and change this to true,
// you can call this, but it will run once...
if (false) {
  $('#resdatatable > tbody tr').each(function(i, tr) {
    $(tr).find('td').last().createDropDown(statusList);
  });
}

function getResult() {
  return [{
    'id': 1,
    'bookingdatetime': '2019-11-01',
    'name': 'John Doe',
    //'class': '',
    //'pickupdatetime': '',
    //'duration': '',
    //'dropdatetime': '',
    'age': 18,
    //'coverage': '',
    //'quote': '',
    'status': 'Confirmed'
  }, {
    'id': 2,
    'bookingdatetime': '2019-11-01',
    'name': 'Jane Doe',
    //'class': '',
    //'pickupdatetime': '',
    //'duration': '',
    //'dropdatetime': '',
    'age': 21,
    //'coverage': '',
    //'quote': '',
    'status': 'Open'
  }, {
    'id': 3,
    'bookingdatetime': '2019-11-08',
    'name': 'Mary Sue',
    //'class': '',
    //'pickupdatetime': '',
    //'duration': '',
    //'dropdatetime': '',
    'age': 16,
    //'coverage': '',
    //'quote': '',
    'status': 'Closed'
  }, {
    'id': 4,
    'bookingdatetime': '2019-12-15',
    'name': 'Charlie Brown',
    //'class': '',
    //'pickupdatetime': '',
    //'duration': '',
    //'dropdatetime': '',
    'age': 25,
    //'coverage': '',
    //'quote': '',
    'status': 'Unknown'
  }];
}

function getStatusList() {
  return [{
    id: 'Confirmed',
    text: 'Confirmed'
  }, {
    id: 'Unconfirmed',
    text: 'Unconfirmed'
  }, {
    id: 'Open',
    text: 'Open'
  }, {
    id: 'Closed',
    text: 'Closed'
  }, {
    id: 'Canceled',
    text: 'Canceled'
  }];
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/css/dataTables.material.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="resdatatable" class="table table-striped" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Booking Date</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <!-- <th>Class</th> -->
      <!-- <th>Pick Up</th> -->
      <!-- <th>Duration</th> -->
      <!-- <th>Drop Off</th> -->
      <th>Age</th>
      <!-- <th>Coverage</th> -->
      <!-- <th>Quote</th> -->
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much - super awesome and complex, but could you leave in my ajax, I am having trouble combining it with the code you just posted.

Comment: @tony Just assign the data in `getStatusList()` somewhere and add the renderer. Just change the last column to `{ data: 'status', title: 'Status', renderer: function(data, type, row) { ... } }`.

Comment: Man, I am even more confused, I did this but it's not working: function getResult() {
   $.ajax({
    type : 'get',
    url  : 'reservations2.php?city=la',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success :  function(result)
    {
      return result;
      console.log (result);

    }
   });
  }

Comment: @tony So you can no longer get your JSON? That seems to be an issue on your end. My example is complete and minimal and shows exactly how to add the renderer. If anything, I am confused. Just add the renderer to the column and make sure the status list object array exists in your application.

Comment: Yeah, it's totally a problem on my end, and it's a lack of understanding on my end too. Your work is 100% and it is much appreciated. It would be awesome if you could help me figure out my problem though.